# Асинхронная загрузка файлов с dropmefiles

Tags: python, requests, asyncio

```
async def get_file_from_dmf(url: str,path):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(
                'https://drop1.dropmefile.com/dl' + urlparse(url).path,
                headers={'referer': url}, ssl=False
        ) as response:
            file_name = response.headers['Content-Disposition'][22:-1]
            if 'txt' not in file_name:
                return False
            with open(path, 'wb') as file:
                while True:
                    chunk = await response.content.read(1024)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    file.write(chunk)
                return True
url = "https://dropmefiles.com/oCXcN"
asyncio.run(get_file_from_dmf(url,"test.txt"))
```

Есть такой метод, который принимает ссылку на дропмифайл и скачивает текстовик из нее асинхронно,но с большими файлами он не работает. В чем проблема? Как сделать, чтобы все скачивалось?В примере ссылка с большим файлом.